# Retrieve my own watchHistory playlist ID

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Since September 12, 2016 youtube disabled the "contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchHistory" method on their API, but they stated that:

"The properties are only visible to an authorized user retrieving data about the user's own channel".

I'm trying to get my own WatchHistory playlist ID using "channels.list" and setting the option mine to true, but I can't retrieve the playlist ID.

Is there any way to get the ID and then call "playlistItems.list" to get all the videos in my Watch History ?

Answer (score 1):

As I understood from latest changelog:

- `Watch History` Playlist ID is `HL`
- `Watch Later` Playlist ID is `WL`

Comment: but if you query "playlistItems.list" with playlist ID: "HL" you get a empty list (as it says in the changelog), but it also says that own user playlist can be retireved, so, do I need to use a different API  method ?

Comment: And that is what I cannot understand. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history says it will be **always empty list**. Google did not leave any way to retrieve these lists.